# where is the Yuidoc data.json address for ember?

Tags: ember.js

I want to merge the ember.js documentation into my local yuidoc documentation for my project since many of my objects extend Ember Objects.

The [Yuidoc Documentation](http://yui.github.com/yuidoc/args/index.html#external-data) says I can put a property "external.data" in my yuidoc.json file with the address to an external data.json file. Is this file available? If not, can it be made available so those of us documenting our ember projects can auto-sync to ember's documentation?

I believe the file is generated when you run 'yuidoc .' and it is located in the same dir as the index.html file that is built for API documentation (the root of the api docs). There is a file in the git repo [here](https://github.com/emberjs/website/blob/master/data/api.yml) that looks like it might've been generated by this data.json file but it obviously does not contain json format. It would be nice if this data.json file were made available at the root of the published api docs on the [ember website](http://emberjs.com)

Answer (score 1):

We don't currently commit this file. Can you open an issue on https://github.com/emberjs/website so we can address this?